# C++ int to string conversion

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

Current source code:

```
string itoa(int i)
{
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream out;
    out << i;
    s = out.str();
    return s;
}

class Gregorian
{
    public:
        string month;
        int day;
        int year;    //negative for BC, positive for AD


        // month day, year
        Gregorian(string newmonth, int newday, int newyear)
        {
            month = newmonth;
            day = newday;
            year = newyear;
        }

        string twoString()
        {
            return month + " " + itoa(day) + ", " + itoa(year);
        }

};
```

And in my main:

```
Gregorian date = new Gregorian("June", 5, 1991);
cout << date.twoString();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
mayan.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
mayan.cc:109:51: error: conversion from ‘Gregorian*’ to non-scalar type ‘Gregorian’ requested
```

Does anyone know why int to string conversion is failing in here? I'm fairly new to C++ but am familiar with Java, I've spent a good deal of time looking for a straightforward answer to this problem but am currently stumped.

Comment: You can get rid of `std::string s;` in `itoa` and just `return out.str();`. The return string will be constructed before the stringstream is destroyed. Reasonable compilers will likely produce the exact same code in both cases, but the extra temporary tends to suggest to people looking at your code that you don't understand or trust the C++ scoping rules.

Comment: Unrelated, but did you mean to name the function `toString()`?

Comment: Coming from Java, I didn't know if C++ already had a toString() method. I didn't want to overload it if I didn't need to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are assigning a `Gregorian` pointer to a `Gregorian`. Drop the `new`:

```
Gregorian date("June", 5, 1991);
```

Comment: Wow, that was an incredibly fast response. A big thank you for such a simple solution.

Comment: @SamMeow no problem. If the answer is OK then you can select it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert int to string, after including sstream:

```
#include <sstream>

string IntToString (int a)
{
    stringstream temp;
    temp<<a;
    return temp.str();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.